# Trying to display correlating modal content when modal trigger is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm struggling to create my own simple modal experience for my portfolio. All I'm trying to do is let the user click an image and have a modal box pop up with the information that correlates to the image clicked. Thats all well and fine, however I can't seem to get Jquery to do this programmatically. I'm rusty with my Javascript and something isn't clicking in my brain, i know this shouldn't be hard.

Here is my html

```
 <div class="projects">
    <div class="projects__grid">
      <a class="modal-trigger" data-target="modal1">
        <div class="projects__image">
          <div class="modal" id="modal1">
            <div class="project__desc modal-content">
              <p class="text">1st modal test --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptas laborum, porro dignissimos quis quod eius. Cupiditate, laborum, eligendi eaque magni maiores placeat, sint voluptate quos dicta ad fugit corporis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a class="modal-trigger" data-target="modal2">
        <div class="projects__image">
          <div class="modal" id="modal2">
            <div class="project__desc modal-content">
              <p class="text">2nd modal test --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptas laborum, porro dignissimos quis quod eius. Cupiditate, laborum, eligendi eaque magni maiores placeat, sint voluptate quos dicta ad fugit corporis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

sure I could just create custom classes or id's for every modal trigger, but I want to keep my code DRY. I've tried:

`$(this, '.modal-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this, '.modal').toggle();
})`

and many other similar attacking angles. What am I missing here? I just need to retrieve the nested ID for the related modal content from whichever modal-trigger is clicked. I know I have to use 'this' somehow but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for any insight, sorry if this has been posted before, I couldn't find anything that answered my question..somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a fiddle, where this should work

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kh4gsLL/)

```
 $('.modal-trigger').click(function(event) {
    let modalExample = $(this).find('.modal');
    modalExample.toggle();
});
```

You have to remove this in your click-event

Comment: Omg, I can't believe how close I was, and how simple of a solution it is lol. So I had the right basic concept, but in order to actually retrieve the related class you need to use the .find() method...Thanks a lot mate, 2 hours of confusion by me was solved in a matter of minutes by you! Thank you!

Comment: With a username like that you gotta help.. :)

Comment: Do you happen to know why when trying to add anchor tags inside the modal-content, it refuses to open? Does .find() have some weird thing against anchor tags?  It works with basic text and images, but not links.

here is the updated JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5kh4gsLL/1/